# How to get a file from a Database and put it in an FTP?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page that gets a list of documents available in a database through a DataGridview and I want that when the users clicks on the link of the document he want's to sent it as an FTP or HTTP document, like if it was on a drive on the server.

The problema I have is that I know that when the file is on a drive it is easy but if it is on the database I do not know how to serve it to the web page user.

I thougth maybe that when de user clicks on the link to save the file to a temp directory, and then redirect the page to that page with the name of the file, but I do not know if it is to much of a touble and there is a better way. Of course if I do this I will have to delete the file from the drive after it has been downloaded.

Comment: So you have your file stored in the database correct and not just the path?? Check these:http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20 and http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120606-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good explanation, and completed the one I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the way to do this, is just a matter of use

```
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
        //Response.BinaryWrite(foto);
        Response.OutputStream.Write(foto, 0, foto.Length);
```

The file, is in binary.